# view pop up on app start

Tags: java, android, xml

I had an application which have option to choose language at start. Currently when the application start i had to click on choose language and then pop up appears containing different languages. But i don't want to click on choose language option for displaying pop up. I want my app to automatically appears a pop up to choose language on app start.
I followed http://programmerguru.com/android-tutorial/android-localization-example tutorial.
Here is the snapshot of the thing i want .
[click to view the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TUqIc.png)

Here is a code of Mainactivity.java

```html
public class AndroidLocalize extends Activity {
 Spinner spinnerctrl;
 Button btn;
 Locale myLocale;

 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.main);
  spinnerctrl = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
  spinnerctrl.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

   public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int pos, long id) {

    if (pos == 1) {

     Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(),
       "You have selected Tamil", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
       .show();
     setLocale("ta");
    } else if (pos == 2) {

     Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(),
       "You have selected Hindi", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
       .show();
     setLocale("hi");
    } else if (pos == 3) {

     Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(),
       "You have selected English", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
       .show();
     setLocale("en");
    }
    else if (pos == 4) {

     Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(),
       "You have selected Arabic", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
       .show();
     setLocale("ar");
    }

   }

   public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   }

  });
 }

 public void setLocale(String lang) {

  myLocale = new Locale(lang);
  Resources res = getResources();
  DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
  Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
  conf.locale = myLocale;
  res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);
  Intent refresh = new Intent(this, AndroidLocalize.class);
  startActivity(refresh);
 }
}
```

Here is code of code of main.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/greet"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/greet"
        android:textSize="25sp" android:gravity="center" android:paddingTop="25sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/sachin" android:paddingTop="25sp" />

    <TextView
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/langselection"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" android:gravity="center" android:paddingTop="25sp"/>
    
    
 <Spinner
     android:popupBackground="#ff004372"
     android:id="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:entries="@array/languages"
       android:gravity="center" android:paddingTop="25sp" />

</LinearLayout>a
```

Comment: anyone can answer please?

Answer (score 0):

if you are using material alert dialog you must show it in onCreate of the launcher activity so that it is the very first code that runs after launcher activity is created.

Hope this helps.